# Access array value from Ruby Enumerator block

Tags: ruby, arrays, enumerable

How can I access the array from within block in Ruby?

For example:

```
[1,2,3].each{|e| puts THEWHOLEARRAY.inspect }
```

Where `THEWHOLEARRAY` should return `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeking is either `tap`, already implemented:

```
[1, 2, 3].tap { |ary|
  puts ary.inspect
  ary.each { |e|
    # ...
  }
  'hello' ' ' + 'world' # return value demo
} # returns the original array
```

Or `ergo` method, coming soon:

```
class Object; def ergo; yield self end end # gotta define it manually as of Ruby 2.0.0
[1, 2, 3].ergo { |ary|
  puts ary.inspect
  ary.each { |e|
    # ...
  }
  'hello' ' ' + 'world' # return value demo
} # returns the block return value
```

Comment: Amazing here is that during the day I saw this `tap` quite a few times and wanted to find out more :-)

Comment: @IlyaNovojilov: Functional programming and `tap` is the new fad nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you want to do. Do you mean something like this?:

```
THEWHOLEARRAY = [1,2,3]
THEWHOLEAREAY.each{ |e|
  puts THEWHOLEARRAY.inspect
}
```

Ruby lets you access variables outside a block. Typically it would be another variable, not the one you are iterating over though.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The block variable only holds information about a single element for each iteration. It does not have information of the whole array. Furthermore, `each` will iterate as many times as the number of the elements in the array. Do you want to inspect that many times? It does not make sense.

Comment: Actually the task is to select elements of the array which are `like` some other array element and return element if there are no `similar` elements.
Like:
`[
{title:'h1',value:'ttt'},
{title:'h2',value:'h2'},
{title:'h1',category:5,value:'needs to be returned instead instead of first one}
]`

What is the better way to do this?